# Conflict with Get-Item

Tags: sql, powershell, get-childitem

I have a line of code that has some conflict in it and I just cannot see what it is.

Here is the program

```
$Date = Get-Date -Format MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss-tt

<#*****SQL Session Variables*****#>
$Username = "sa"
$Password = "xyz" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$Password)

$DatabaseNames = Invoke-SQLcmd -Query "Select * From sys.databases WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%Master%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Tempdb%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Model%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Msdb%';" -ServerInstance "localhost" | Select Name -ExpandProperty Name
Write-Host "****Database Names****" -ForeGroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black
$DatabaseNames
"`n`n"

<#****Get Database Size****#>
Push-Location
Import-Module sqlps -disablenamechecking
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select name, physical_name, size * 8.0 / 1024 size from sys.master_files WHERE Type_Desc NOT LIKE '%LOG%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Master%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Tempdb%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Model%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Msdb%';" -ServerInstance "localhost" | Select @{Label="Database Name";Expression={$_.name}}, @{Label="Location";Expression={$_.physical_name}}, @{Label="SIze (MB)";Expression={$_.size}}
Pop-Location
"`n"
Start-Sleep 4

<#****Backup Databases****#>
ForEach ($DatabaseName in $DatabaseNames)
{
$SQLBackupPath1 = "C:\T2\SQlBackup\"
$SQLBackupPath2 = "$DatabaseName"
$SQLBackupPath3 = "_"
$SQLBackupPath4 = $Date
$SQLBackupPath5 = "_.bak"
$SQLBackupPath = $SQLBackupPath1 + $SQLBackupPath2 + $SQLBackupPath3 + $SQLBackupPath4 + $SQLBackupPath5
$SQLBackupPath

Backup-SQLDatabase -ServerInstance localhost -Database $DatabaseName -BackupFile $SQLBackupPath -Credential $Credentials
Write-Host "Database Backup of " -NoNewLine
Write-Host "$DatabaseName" -ForeGroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black -NoNewLine
Write-Host " has been completed" 
"`n"
}

<#****Delete Databases****#>
ForEach ($DatabaseName in $DatabaseNames)
{
Push-Location
Import-Module sqlps -disablenamechecking
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'$DatabaseName';" -ServerInstance "localhost"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE [master];" -ServerInstance "localhost"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "ALTER DATABASE [$DatabaseName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;" -ServerInstance "localhost"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "DROP DATABASE [$DatabaseName];" -ServerInstance "localhost"
Pop-Location
Write-Host "Database: " -NoNewLine
Write-Host "$DatabaseName" -ForeGroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black -NoNewLine
Write-Host " has been Dropped"
"`n"
}

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\T2\SQLBackup\ | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "ApOps*" } | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

If I move the final GetChildItem line under the first line $Date I get output. However if I use this in a loop or where it currently sits no results are returned. This makes me believe that there is some conflicting statement in the code. If so I cannot seem to find it and I am losing my mind looking for it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're being bitten by the output formatting, and being a bit careless with your output. Consider this, I'm in a directory with a couple of files:

List the files, simple and works fine:

```
PS D:\test> Get-ChildItem  # list the files


    Directory: D:\test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                 
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                 
-a----       02/11/2016     07:01           1640 log.txt                                                                                              
-a----       02/11/2016     07:01              0 testfile
```

Output an empty string, then list the files, simple and works fine. One blank line extra at the start:

```
PS D:\test> ""; Get-ChildItem



    Directory: D:\test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                 
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                 
-a----       02/11/2016     07:01           1640 log.txt                                                                                              
-a----       02/11/2016     07:01              0 testfile
```

Get the string length, then list the files. Wait what? The output formatter is taking property you asked for from the first output it receives (string Length) and is then applying that to everything it receives (files) until the pipeline is empty:

```
PS D:\test> "" | select Length; Get-ChildItem  # select string length, then...

Length     # missing columns ??!!
------     
     0     # string length
  1640     # file length
     0     # file length
```

Get some property which doesn't exist, then list the files. This is the same idea, only this time it's not showing anything for the string or anything for the files, because `Foobar` doesn't exist on either type:

```
PS D:\test> "" | select Foobar; Get-ChildItem   # select property which doesn't exist

Foobar
------
         # ????  this is your "no output"
```

You are doing this kind of thing - sending mixed types to the output pipeline. They still go to the output, if you captured them in variables or wrote them to files the data would be there, but the output formatter which tries to work out how to display them on the console takes the first thing it gets and formats the output against that, assuming you'll have a consistent output. And the first complex objects it gets come from your code here:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select name, physical_name, size * 8.0 / 1024 size from sys.master_files WHERE Type_Desc NOT LIKE '%LOG%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Master%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Tempdb%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Model%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Msdb%';" -ServerInstance "localhost" | Select @{Label="Database Name";Expression={$_.name}}, @{Label="Location";Expression={$_.physical_name}}, @{Label="SIze (MB)";Expression={$_.size}}


# where you select these properties for display:
# Database Name, Location, Size (MB)

# None of these properties exist on files or directories,
# so they don't get shown on screen.
```

Fix:

```
$x = Invoke-SqlCmd ___
$y = Get-ChildItem

$x | Format-Table
$y | Format-Table
```

Or use more Write-Host, or output to files.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. I basically had to read it a few times to understand what you were talking about but to boil it down. You were saying to get rid of the | Format-Table as it looks pretty on screen but screws up the data in the variable. Once I did that I was back in business. Sorry it took me so long to accept this answer I forgot about it.

Comment: I often do say that, and that's true, but what I was mostly saying was when you mix types in the output stream, the auto-formatter gets confused and can't show all the things, so it looks like some go missing, and you have to work around it.